# In C#, how do you check if between two times?

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to figure out if a DateTime is between two Dates as well as two times.

For example,

```
if DateTime.Now >= January && DateTime.Now < August && DateTime.Now >= 9am && DateTime.Now < 12pm
     //do something
```

I'm not really sure how to go about this, any help is appreciated :')

Comment: Side recommendation, you should assign `DateTime.Now` to a variable and use that variable in all of your calculations, so that the same value is being used in all parts of the comparison. Otherwise, the value of `DateTime.Now` could be inconsistent throughout your conditional.

Comment: Unless `January` and `August` are variable names, the value on the right side of each comparison is not a `DateTime`.  You need to construct a `DateTime` against which to compare `DateTime.Now`.  Have you tried anything beyond those arbitrary literals?

Answer (score -1):

```
if (DateTime.Now.Month < 8 && DateTime.Now.Hour >= 9 && DateTime.Now.Hour < 12) {
 // do your thing
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8#properties:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Month >= 1 && DateTime.Now.Month < 8
    && DateTime.Now.Hour >= 9  && DateTime.Now.Hour < 12)
```

where `DateTime.Month` is a number between 1 and 12, and `DateTime.Hour` is a number between 0 and 23.

Comment: Checking if month is >= 1 is useless since there is no month that is lower than 1.

Comment: That's correct, I wrote this as a "template" which can be adapted, for that special case it actually doesn't make sense.